# Need help in understanding pyspark execution on yarn as Master

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have already some picture of yarn architecture as well as spark architecture.But when I try to understand them together(thats what happens 
when apark job runs on YARN as master) on a Hadoop cluster, I am getting in to some confusions.So first I will say my understanding with below example and then I will
come to my confusions

Say I have a file "orderitems" stored on HDFS with some  replication factor.
Now I am processing the data by reading this file in to a spark RDD (say , for calculating order revenue). 
I have written the code and configured the spark submit as given below

```
    spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --conf spark.ui.port=21888 \
    --num-executors 2 \
    --executor-memory 512M \
    src/main/python/order_revenue.py
```

Lets assume that I have created the RDD with a partition of 5 and I have executed in yarn-client mode.

Now As per my understanding , once I submit the spark job on YARN,

- Request goes to Application manager which is a component of resource
  manager.
- Application Manager will find one node manager and ask it to launch a 
  container.
- This is the first container of an application and we will call it an 
  Application Master.
- Application master takes over the responsibility of executing and monitoring 
  the job.

Since I have submitted on client mode,driver program will run on my edge Node/Gateway Node.
I have provided num-executors as 2 and executor memory as 512 mb

Also I have provided no.of partitions for RDD as 5 which means , it will create 5 partitions of data read 
and distribute over 5 nodes.

Now here my few confusions over this

> - I have read in user guide that, partitions of rdd will be distributed    to different nodes. Does these nodes are same as the
>     'Data Nodes' of    HDFS cluster? I mean here its 5 partitions, does
>     this mean its in 5    data nodes?
> - I have mentioned num-executors as 2.So this 5 partitions of data will    utilizes 2 executors(CPU).So my nextquestion is ,  from where
>     this 2    executors (CPU) will be picked? I mean 5 partitions are in 5 nodes
>     right , so    does these 2 executors are also in any of these nodes?
> - The scheduler is responsible for allocating resources to the various    running applications subject to constraints of capacities,
>     queues    etc. And also a Container is a Linux Control Group which is
>     a linux    kernel feature that allows users to allocate
>     CPU,memory,Disk I/O and    Bandwidth to a user process. So my final
>     question is Containers are    actually provided by "scheduler"?

I am confused here. I have referred architecture, release document and some videos and got messed up.

Expecting helping hands here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions first:

1) Very simply, Executor is spark's worker node and driver is manager node and have nothing to do with hadoop nodes.  Assume executors to be processing units (say 2 here) and repartition(5) divides data in 5 chunks to be by these 2 executors and on some basis these data chunks will be divided amongst 2 executors. Repartition data does not create nodes

Spark cluster architecture:

[image]

**Spark on yarn client mode:**
[image]

**Spark on yarn cluster mode:**
[image]

For other details you can read the blog post https://sujithjay.com/2018/07/24/Understanding-Apache-Spark-on-YARN/

and https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture/